# где найти avg_atom в /proc?

Tags: ubuntu

Есть такое задание:

> Для всех зарегистрированных в данный момент в системе процессов выведите в один файл строки
>
> ProcessID=PID : Parent_ProcessID=PPID : Average_Sleeping_Time=SleepAVG
>
> Значения PPid и Pid возьмите из файлов status, значение SleepAVG из файла sched поле **avg_atom**, которые находятся в директориях с названиями, соответствующими PID процессов в /proc.

Проблема в том что его там нет.(смотрите на изображение)

Вопрос в том, где я смогу его достать или, если его нет, как мне его вычислить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в коде [программы linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3e2014637c50e5d6a77cd63d5db6c209fe29d1b1/kernel/sched/debug.c#L987) значение `avg_atom` вычисляется так:

```
avg_atom = p->se.sum_exec_runtime;
if (nr_switches)
    avg_atom = div64_ul(avg_atom, nr_switches);
else
    avg_atom = -1LL;
```

соответственно, если эта программа собрана так, что в интерфейсе `/proc` не отображается `avg_atom`, то можно посчитать его самостоятельно, разделив `sum_exec_runtime` на `nr_switches` (а если `nr_switches` равно нулю, то вернуть `-1`)